# UI-Grid: How to disable '1' when sorting?

Tags: angular-ui-grid

How do I disable the '1' that shows up every time I try to sort my column?

Here is a plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/gKqt8JEo2FukS3URRLJ5?p=preview

You can see, that when you sort, `'1'` shows up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easier than I thought:

```
.ui-grid-sort-priority-number{
  font-size: 0;
}
```